# POST data to Foundation Emails 2

Tags: email, templates, zurb-foundation

We'd like to develop our email templates using Foundation Emails 2, host those templates locally and be able to POST data and have the template filled-in with that data (via Panini/Handlebars). This doesn't appear to be a use case that is supported out of the box, but it seemed like an obvious feature -- am I missing something?